# when I press Enter in an EditText (password) it goes to a new line then if executes the setOnEditorActionListener

Tags: android

when I press Enter in an EditText (password) it goes to a new line then if executes the setOnEditorActionListener so my password will be incorrect (bcz the Enter is added).
any solution plz ?

EDIT:
when I added: android:singleLine="true" the button "Enter" in the phone's keyboard will be replace with "Done"
so how to keep the button "Enter" when I add android:singleLine="true".

Comment: <EditText android:singleLine="true" />

Comment: if I add it I can't press Enter. the enter will be replaced with "Done"

Comment: "Done" doesn't appears because of you have added android:singleLine="true" to EditText properties.It may be coming because EditText (password) is your last view in layout.

Answer (score 2):

you can set maximum lenght or force a single row.

Force single row :

```
<EditText android:singleLine="true" />
```

Set maximum lenght:

```
<EditText android:maxLength="12" />
```

Hope it help

Comment: when I limit it when I write a password length 10 and I press enter it will take the enter. and when I write "<EditText android:singleLine="true" />" I can't press the enter in the keyboard because the Enter button will be replaced with "Done" button.

Comment: If password is your last view in the layout then you will have Done in the keyboard. can you post your code so we can help you ?

Answer (score 0):

set maximum length for password

```
android:maxLength="12"
```

Comment: I can't limit my password length. Even when I limited it and if I wrote a password length 10 and I press enter it will take the enter

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line:

```
     android:lines="1"
```